# How can I receive data using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, sockets, express

I am running a server using expressjs. Whenever a user accesses to one of my specific url (for this purpose, just imagine it will be `https://server.com/test`), I want to emit a data to another webserver using socketio, listen to the data and respond to the user with the data I have received.

Few things to note:

1. My server expects nothing but just an access to the `https://server.com/test` url.
2. Another server, which I want to connect using socket.io and obtain data expects me to send an argument of `{"got" : "true"}` to parameter called `"test"`.
3. When another server receives the socket emit from my server on parameter "test" with arguments specified above, it simply replies back with an argument `{"message" : "true"}`

My code is quite simple and looks like this (router) :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
//const Goal = require("../models/battery_message");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const io = require("socket.io-client");

const host = "https://another_server.com"
const socket = io(host, {query:"email=edmund@gmail.com"});
console.log("connected");


router.get('/', function(req,res) {
    socket.emit("test_me", {"got" : "true"}, function(data){
        exists = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The problem I have is whenever the user accesses my server on `https://server.com/test` nothing happens, as no response comes like in an infinite loop. My guess is that I need some kind of another socket.emit because another server probably emits its response to the socket too, but I might be wrong.

So to sum up, my question is, what do I need to add in order to successfully get the response from another server?

Comment: Why do you want to use socket.io for the server-server connection? It looks like all you need is a basic http request. Please give some more context. How is that second server set up? Is it a socket only server? Do you have control over it? Why this convoluted setup?

Comment: @ChrisG To be honest, I did not check with simple HTTP requests but I know that idea of server-server looks stupid, I just need that for a demo and will be redoing it later. Regarding the control, I do not have for the second server. If we talk about http requests, shall I test it by simply making GET request with arguments specified?

Comment: @ChrisG Second server also expects email as an argument

Comment: Sorry for asking, but does the second server even act as sockets server? I assume you know that this has to be specifically set up that way. Who does control the 2nd server? Is it a website? But yeah, just use HTTP requests. It doesn't sound like server 2 needs to be able to send messages to server 1, which is the only use case for a socket connection here.